# How to login with mediawiki 1.27 api.php using python and urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, mediawiki-api

Since mediawiki 1.27, the login procedere has changed in api.php.

Could please anyone give an example how to login with api.php in mediawiki 1.27 using Python and urllib2?

thx in advance

Comment: See relevant announcements: https://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/mediawiki-api-announce/2016-January/000101.html https://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/mediawiki-api-announce/2016-July/000114.html The old login API still works though, it's just deprecated.

Comment: I am interested in any working code example that works well with 1.27 and urllib2

Comment: Anything that worked in 1.26, I suppose? If you are using for an example of non-deprecated usage, [python-mwapi](https://github.com/mediawiki-utilities/python-mwapi/) does that (it uses requests, not urllib2, but that's not too hard to translate).